# How to start 4 Kinects in a particular order?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am writing a application (in C#) which merges the skeletal data from 4 Kinects. The order in which the sensors are started is very important. I have tried using `KinectSensor.UniqueKinectId` for this, but it is not very reliable, because the sensor which is connected first always has an ID ending with `\0000000000000000`. In addition to that if I connect sensors to different USB ports then the ID changes.
Does anybody have an idea how to use a fixed order of connected Sensors? Using `KinectSensor.UniqueKinectId` or `KinectSensor.DeviceConnectionId` makes the program usable only on a specific machine with specific sensors.

Comment: "with specific sensors", how do you tell them apart if you're not making the program aware of which specific sensors it is talking to?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I meant if you hard code the UniqueIds of sensors I used to develop into the program it might not work on a different PC with the same sensors

Comment: No, but doesn't that just mean that this has to be configurable and you have to specify for the program which sensors it should talk to, and the identifying bits?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I did some testing and the ID's of the sensors seem to change if I connect it to a different USB hub

Comment: Then "how to start 4 kinects in a particular order" is really "How do I tell which kinect is which", isn't it? Also, does it matter if they change, you're not going to create a system where the way you connect the kinects are going to change all that much are you? I'm guessing that you're creating a system where when you turn it on, it just starts, it wouldn't change all that much hardware-wise, would it?

Comment: yes. the aim of the program is to capture when the person is turning around, so the Kinects are around the person in a circle and I switch between them depending which ones the person is facing

Comment: So again, wouldn't the unique identifier be enough them, or does these id's change every time you boot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69655/discussion-between-helena-lissenko-and-lasse-v-karlsen).